# Loop - Do , while

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I tried doing a loop, but the "{" symbols prevent the all the print lines from repeating I think.  I want the loop to redisplay the entire first string after the user finishes entering values for the sequence.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FtoC{

    static Scanner cin = new Scanner (System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char userInput = ' ';
        System.out.print("\nEnter " + "\"F\"" + " or " + "\"f\"" + " for Fahrenheit to Celsius"
                      + "\nEnter " + "\"C\"" + " or " +  "\"c\"" + " for Celsius to Fahrenheit"
                      + "\nEnter something else to quit." +"\n");


         userInput = cin.next().charAt(0);

        if ((userInput == 'F') || (userInput =='f'))
        {print("Enter a temp in Fahrenheit"
                +"\n I will tell you temp in Celsius" +"\n");
            far2cel();
        }
         else if ((userInput == 'C') || (userInput =='c')) {
            print("Enter a temp in Celsius:"
            +"\n I will tell you temp in fahrenheit" +"\n");
                cel2far();
        } else {
            print("Terminating the program" + "\n");
        }
    }

    private static void cel2far() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Double celsius = input.nextDouble();
        print(celsius + " celsius is " + ((celsius * 9 / 5.0) + 32)
                + " Fahrenheit");

    }

    private static void far2cel() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Double Fahrenheit = input.nextDouble();
        print(Fahrenheit + " Fahrenheit is " + ((Fahrenheit - 32) * (5 / 9.0))
                + " celsius");

    }

    private static void print(String string) {
        System.out.print("\n" + string);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a loop.  Could you edit this to post the loop code you tried?

Comment: Are you seriously asking about a do-while loop, without a single loop in your code? Try this: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+do+while&oq=java+do+while

Comment: "The '{' symbols prevent the all the print lines from repeating" Er, no. Time to read the old tutorial.

Comment: I'd like to help you find the problem with what you tried.  To make that easier for me, can you post the thing with the loop that you tried, not some other piece of code, please?

Comment: Why `cin` if you're going to instantiate a `Scanner input` in every method? And, how many `{` symbols did you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that I get what you want exactly, but this way you can run the program until user enters something different than "F", "f", "C", "C" in the first part of the program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FtoC{

    static Scanner cin = new Scanner (System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        while(true) {
            char userInput = ' ';
            System.out.print("\nEnter " + "\"F\"" + " or " + "\"f\"" + " for Fahrenheit to Celsius"
                          + "\nEnter " + "\"C\"" + " or " +  "\"c\"" + " for Celsius to Fahrenheit"
                          + "\nEnter something else to quit." +"\n");

             userInput = cin.next().charAt(0);

            if ((userInput == 'F') || (userInput =='f'))
            {print("Enter a temp in Fahrenheit"
                    +"\n I will tell you temp in Celsius" +"\n");
                far2cel();
            }
             else if ((userInput == 'C') || (userInput =='c')) {
                print("Enter a temp in Celsius:"
                +"\n I will tell you temp in fahrenheit" +"\n");
                    cel2far();
            } else {
                print("Terminating the program" + "\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void cel2far() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Double celsius = input.nextDouble();
        print(celsius + " celsius is " + ((celsius * 9 / 5.0) + 32)
                + " Fahrenheit");

    }

    private static void far2cel() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Double Fahrenheit = input.nextDouble();
        print(Fahrenheit + " Fahrenheit is " + ((Fahrenheit - 32) * (5 / 9.0))
                + " celsius");

    }

    private static void print(String string) {
        System.out.print("\n" + string);
    }
}
```

I have placed it into while loop and added "break;" in the "Terminating program" part.

Comment: Thanks.  Sometimes the simplest solution is the best.  I kept trying to a "do while" statement, but that wasn't working.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it helped you out! Thanks for chosing me for the best answer, I really appreciate it.